# Creating cs2php compiler using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, class-library

I found an interesting project on GitHub which allows converting C# code to PHP. Link: https://github.com/isukces/cs2php

They Stated: *"You have do download and build cs2php compiler by yourself. Source code is available on GitHub. Binary version is currently not distributed due to Microsoft Rosylin licence limitations."*

I'm having a hard time creating a cs2php.exe compiler. I tried building a Class Library project but all I get is dll file, when I change Output Type to Windows application I receive that I'm missing main method.

How can I compile cs2php.exe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my research, you could download the file in the https://github.com/isukces/cs2php you provided.

First, please open CSToPHP solution.

Second, choose Engine->Lang.Php.Compiler.

Third, Right click Rebuild.

Finally, you will get the cs2php.exe file in the path 'cs2php-master\cs2php-

master\Lang.Cs2Php\bin\Debug\net472\cs2php.exe'.