# Converting Csharp to PHP with cs2php

Tags: c#, php

I tried to execute Piotr isukces csharp to PHP converter https://github.com/isukces/cs2php
After having compiled the **'cs2php.exe'** thanks to another post on this website ([Creating cs2php compiler using Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59012662/creating-cs2php-compiler-using-visual-studio-2017/62643499#62643499)), when I run the command to convert, I got:

```
$ cs2php.exe C:\Users\...\MyThirdPhpCode\MyThirdPhpCode.csproj C:\Users\...\MyThirdPhpCode\
Translate C# -> Php
Output root C:\Users\...\MyThirdPhpCode\
Create Php output files
Success
press any key...
```

A new created PHP file is expected but the output folder is empty (without error message).
My project target is configured to .NET Framework 4.5.

Comment: If you find some tool on Github that doesn't work as expected, start by reading their issues: https://github.com/isukces/cs2php/issues/11 and https://github.com/isukces/cs2php/issues/12 - I would call that a dead project. I would recommend to look for something else, or even better, rewrite it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You Are right  i have already read the issu but poor real experience on project to be able to say that it is dead so thank you for your shared experience

Comment: If it's been broken for more than a year without anyone fixing it, I would consider it pretty dead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @Magnus Eriksson comments, I'll try to rewrite my code and convert manually